# Creating a Day/Hour heatmap in Grafana

Tags: grafana

What would be the best way to create a heatmap similar to [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/tjdecke/5558084) where the counts are bucketed into time hour and day buckets?

Using the built in heatmap as well as the cal-heatmap plugin, it's only possible to create heatmaps over a period of time whereas I would like to aggregate into just the day of the week(monday, tuesday etc.) and the hour of the day.

Comment: there is a new official plugin by Grafana: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels-visualizations/visualizations/heatmap/

Answer (score 8):

The Carpet Plot plugin sounds like it fits this use case: https://grafana.com/plugins/petrslavotinek-carpetplot-panel

Here is a simple example:

[image]

Comment: Hmm I saw this when I was looking through the grafana libraries - the y-axis is perfect but I couldn't find a way to consolidate the x-axis by day of the week. Would that be possible with this library? Ideally The graph would have the time of the day on one axis and the 7 days of the week on the other

Comment: Not sure I follow. It does have the 7 days of the week on the x-axis. Do you mean something else?

Comment: Yeah, I want to be able to aggregate across days of the week. So the axis would be just "mon, tues, wed..." not the last 7 dates. Checkout the [example](http://bl.ocks.org/tjdecke/5558084) I linked.

The goal is to be able to see the highest traffic days of the week/times (ex. mondays at 9am). Does that make sense?

Comment: No, sorry don't think that is currently possible in Grafana - it expects time series data. The closest I could get was to choose the "Previous week" time range. I suppose this panel could be extended to work that way by bucketing per week. You could try opening an issue here: https://github.com/petrslavotinek/grafana-carpetplot/issues

Answer (score 6):

*For future-people that stumble across this (like myself)*

Unfortunately, the Carpet plot plugin has not received updates in 3.5 years, so is no longer maintained. To add to that, [Grafana has a new plugins platform](https://grafana.com/blog/2020/05/18/grafana-v7.0-released-new-plugin-architecture-visualizations-transformations-native-trace-support-and-more/#plugins-platform) based on React, instead of Angular, so I'm not entirely sure if some simple package updates would work on the old carpet plugin. I've tried running it on a new Grafana installation (7+), and it doesn't seem to work out of the box.

There is, however, a community plugin called [Hourly Heatmap for Grafana](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/marcusolsson-hourly-heatmap-panel), and it seems to scratch the same itch. More context is provided in their blogpost [Plugin showcase: The hourly heatmap panel, built on Grafana's new plugin platform](https://grafana.com/blog/2020/06/16/plugin-showcase-the-hourly-heatmap-panel-built-on-grafanas-new-plugin-platform/).

**Edit**: as of July 2022, this plugin has no longer been actively maintained, and the latest known compatible Grafana version seems to be 8.

[image: Hourly heatmap Grafana plugin]

Comment: Carpet Plot seems to work on my 7.x install but happy to hear about more options. Heatmap with hours as the Y-axis should be built in tbh.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I too am looking for what OP is asking -- it's unfortunate that it's only possible to create heatmaps over a period of time whereas I would like to aggregate into just the day of the week (Monday, Tuesday etc.) and the hour of the day.  I.e., ideally The graph would have the time of the day on one axis (Y) and the 7 days of the week on the other (X),  the axis would be just "mon, tues, wed..." not the last 7 dates. If anyone find a plugin for it, please post. thx.

Comment: As of July 2022 this plugin is no longer maintained either.